# How to use Python to convert an octal to a decimal

Tags: python, decimal, octal

I had this little homework assignment and I needed to convert decimal to octal and then octal to decimal. I did the first part and could not figure out the second to save my life. The first part went like this:

```
decimal = int(input("Enter a decimal integer greater than 0: "))

print("Quotient Remainder Octal")
bstring = " "
while decimal > 0:
    remainder = decimal % 8
    decimal = decimal // 8
    bstring = str(remainder) + bstring
    print ("%5d%8d%12s" % (decimal, remainder, bstring))
print("The octal representation is", bstring)
```

I read how to convert it here: [Octal to Decimal](http://www.robotroom.com/NumberSystems4.html), but I have no clue how to turn it into code.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show some effort, SO is no code writing service.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From decimal to octal:

```
oct(42) # '052'
```

Octal to decimal

```
int('052', 8) # 42
```

If you want to return octal as a string then you might want to wrap it in `str`.

Answer (score 4):

#### These first lines take any decimal number and convert it to any desired number base

```
def dec2base():
    a = int(input('Enter decimal number: \t'))
    d = int(input('Enter expected base: \t'))
    b = ""
    while a != 0:
        x = '0123456789ABCDEF'
        c = a % d
        c1 = x[c]
        b = str(c1) + b
        a = int(a // d)
    return (b)
```

#### The second lines do the same but for a given range and a given decimal

```
def dec2base_R():
    a = int(input('Enter start decimal number:\t'))
    e = int(input('Enter end decimal number:\t'))
    d = int(input('Enter expected base:\t'))
    for i in range (a, e):
        b = ""
        while i != 0:
            x = '0123456789ABCDEF'
            c = i % d
            c1 = x[c]
            b = str(c1) + b
            i = int(i // d)
    return (b)
```

#### The third lines convert from any base back to decimal

```
def todec():
    c = int(input('Enter base of the number to convert to decimal:\t'))
    a = (input('Then enter the number:\t ')).upper()
    b = list(a)
    s = 0
    x = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
    for pos, digit in enumerate(b[-1::-1]):
        y = x.index(digit)
        if int(y)/c >= 1:
            print('Invalid input!!!')
            break
        s = (int(y) * (c**pos)) + s
    return (s)
```

Note: I also have the GUI version if anyone needs them

Comment: Very nice! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
def decimal_to_octal(num1):
  new_list = []
  while num1 >= 1:
    num1 = num1/8
    splited = str(num1).split('.')
    num1 = int(splited[0])
    appendednum = float('0.'+splited[1])*8
    new_list.append(int(appendednum))
    decimal_to_octal(num1)    
  return "your number in octal: "+''.join(str(v) for v in new_list[::-1])

print(decimal_to_octal(384))
```

Comment: Adding some comments as to why this answers the original poster's question would be welcome.

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in Python... but I wrote this logic... It works fine.

```
def octToDec(oct):
    lenOct = str(oct)
    le = len(lenOct)
    octal = 0
    for i in (range(le)):
        octal = octal + int(lenOct[i])* pow(8, le-1)
        le -= 1
    print(octal)

octToDec(number)
```