# Convert any string of Octal numbers to decimal numbers in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a function that converts any octal number (input as a string) to a decimal number. Any number can mean "10" or "14 27". So for numbers with whitespace I need to use .split() and be able to return the decimal value in the same format for split strings, so "12 23" would be the return on "14 27"

The function can only accept one input.

Can anyone help or suggest how I can implement this?

My thoughts for the code, in pseudo, which needs a for loop (I'm assuming two for loops, I'm a beginner in Python so apologies)

```
input = "12 23"

new_input = input.split()

for each number in the input:

  get the position of each digit
  
  for each digit in the number:

    multiply the digit by 8 to the power of its position

Return result of adding each digit
```

Comment: You're overthinking this.  Once you've split your string into individual numbers, you can use `int(X, 8)` to directly convert them from octal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Python to convert an octal to a decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35450560/how-to-use-python-to-convert-an-octal-to-a-decimal)

Comment: Please try your own research in the future. I just googled the question title and [that](/q/35450560) was the second result. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: That only works with digits that don't include spaces between them, hence why I was asking my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think list comprehension would be best fitted for this task.

```
input = "12 23"
out = ' '.join([str(int(num, 8)) for num in input.split(' ')])
print(out)  # -> 10 19
```

Does this work?