# Converting Binary Number of List integer Type into Decimal Number?

Tags: python, list, binary, decimal

I know this is kind of weird question. I was developing a program, and suddenly I got stuck a bit strange issue. Let me explain the portion, where I am having an issue:

I have `int type list` variable, where I stored binary values like [image]

Now I want to take as it is and to convert into **Decimal format**. How should I do it?

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21765779/converting-binary-to-decimal-integer-output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to turn the integer to string than again to int using base 2.

Here is an example:

```
x = 111000111100000
dec = int(str(x), 2)
print(dec)  # --> 29152
```

Comment: It worked, thanks alot. Please mark my question up.